# htaccess VS safe redirect manager

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I'm updating a WP theme, changing permalinks, and also migrating to https at same time. Have 1 wildcard redirect (removing categories from URL) and about 140 manual redirects (old joomla links). Need advice between going with htaccess or Safe Redirect Manager. My only concern is page load speed, not extensible features or tracking.

It would seem like htaccess would always be the fastest but my htaccess file is 20kb (because of all the manual redirects). And so I wonder if loading a php plugin on every request (however all redirects intelligently cached) is faster. SRM might seem like the better option considering all the manual redirects but I'm wondering if there are some old-school htaccess phreaks who might say otherwise. I don't want to go through the hassle of testing.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking, can you specify what your exact question is?

Comment: That would be "Need advice between going with htaccess or Safe Redirect Manager. My only concern is page load speed, not extensible features or tracking." at the end of the first paragraph. It seems clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would probably be to put your redirects in the main Apache config. Then this is only processed once when the server is started, rather than a 20kb htaccess being parsed for every request. As for your other option, not sure on the performance impact.

Comment: Annnnnnnnddddd....I feel stupid. For some reason it never occurred to me that it's the server processing http requests and not the other way around. Outside of my technical scope but I could of logically thought of that. 

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it helped. Please mark my answer accepted using the tick at the top left of it, to show the question is resolved. Don't forget to put the initial slash in your match when moving rules from htaccess to main config.

Comment: Can I hire you to do the redirect? :D

Comment: Yes, you can :D

Comment: Contact through your site??

Comment: Yes, please. I linked it from my profile. Sorry, being careful as not sure what the rules are on here.